# php code to display click tracker not working

Tags: php

I have this click-tracking php code for displaying on my site:

```
<?php
if (!file_exists("config.php")) {
    header("Location: installer");
}

require_once("config.php");

//Connect to database
@$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$con) {
    die("Error: Could not connect to database (" . mysql_error() . "). Check your database settings are correct.");
}

//Check database exists
$does_db_exist = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $con);
if (!$does_db_exist) {
    die("Error: Database does not exist (" . mysql_error() . "). Check your database  settings are correct.");
}

if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
} else {
    die("Error: ID cannot be blank.");
}

//If ID exists, show count or else die
$showinfo = mysql_query("SELECT count FROM Data WHERE id = \"$id\"");
$showresult = mysql_fetch_assoc($showinfo);
if ($showresult != 0) {
    echo $showresult["count"];
} else {
    die("Error: ID does not exist.");
}

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

I want to show the number of times the file was downloaded with this given code, by inserting this code in my HTML so it displays how many times it was downloaded, but it's not working:

```
<?php
$_GET["id"] = "download1";
include("indication/display.php");
?>
```

I placed that code in my HTML but it doesn't show the number

Comment: **[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code.](http://bit.ly/phpmsql)** They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the **[red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)**? Learn about _[prepared statements](http://j.mp/T9hLWi)_ instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @MartyMcVry your comment isn't accurate until 5.5 goes stable - it's still in beta. Not that I disagree with the advice to stop using mysql_ functions.

Comment: @AD7six there is nothing wrong in telling  about old aoi which will bw depricated in new versions imho

Comment: @NullPonyPointer I agree, but the _comment_ (which is pasted all over SO) is inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

1) to count rows:

```
$showinfo = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(count) FROM Data WHERE id ='$id'");
$showresult = mysql_num_rows($showinfo);
if ($showresult !== 0) {
```

2) I consider that you have a donwload link, sth like that:

```
echo '<a href=index.php?id=download>Download</a>';
```

3) I cannot see the UPDATE db (adding one value every time sb clicks download)

```
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
$showinfo = mysql_query("UPDATE Data SET id = '$id' + 1 ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

```
'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Data WHERE id = '.intval($id)
```

This is faster than COUNT(id), very very slightly.

And as everyone said please use PDO.